# Send notification via OneSignal - how to enable sound

Tags: ios, push-notification, onesignal

I am using the following code to send notification from user to user via OneSignal. It works well except I cannot manage to produce sound on receiving of the notification. Does anybody know what I am missing? This code is taken from their example project at https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK

```
    let status: OSPermissionSubscriptionState = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()
    let pushToken = status.subscriptionStatus.pushToken
    let userId = status.subscriptionStatus.userId


    if pushToken != nil {
        let message = "This is a notification's message or body"
        let notificationContent = [
            "include_player_ids": [userId],
            "contents": ["en": message], // Required unless "content_available": true or "template_id" is set
            "headings": ["en": "Notification Title"],
            "subtitle": ["en": "An English Subtitle"],
            // If want to open a url with in-app browser
            //"url": "https://google.com",
            // If you want to deep link and pass a URL to your webview, use "data" parameter and use the key in the AppDelegate's notificationOpenedBlock
            "data": ["OpenURL": "https://imgur.com"],
            "ios_attachments": ["id" : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/16/15/17/hot-air-balloons-1984308_1280.jpg"],
            "ios_badgeType": "Increase",
            "ios_badgeCount": 1,
            ] as [String : Any]

        OneSignal.postNotification(notificationContent)
    }
```

The push notification is sent from an iPad to the same device intentionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three basic things (`alert`, `badge`, `sound`) in payload which must have otherwise it'll miss on execution, the sample payload should be like following. [See Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)

```
{
 “aps” : {
 “alert” : “Your message here.”,
 “sound” : “default”,
 “badge” : 9
 }
}
```

the `default` keyword will play default sound of Notification, and you can also play your custom sound like `“sound” : “sound.wav”,`

**EDITED**

In Onesignal it is like this `"ios_sound": "sound.wav"` to play custom sound [see here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-sounds#section-how-to-add-custom-sounds)

In Onesignal you can't play default sound [see here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-sounds#section-can-i-set-a-default-sound-)

Hope this will help.

Comment: It sounds like it should fix it, but I tried both `"ios_sound": "default"` and `"ios_sound": "sound.wav"` and neither produces a sound on notification receiving

Comment: I had muted notification sounds. Umuted them now and your solution works. Thanks.

Comment: Great, Happy coding.